# Discord.js adding role upon guildMemberAdd doesn't always work

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm having an issue with Discord.js v12 and Node.js v15.7.0.

Here's the code :

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  var i = "336796839582105600";
  var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === i);
  member.roles.add(role).then(console.log('Role added: ' + member.id));
});
```

The code seems to be working flawlessly on the discord server I'm using for development.
But when used in production on a discord server with more than 2500k users, the code is executed, the audit log shows the bot adding the role as intended, but when you look at the user profile, no role is showing up until someone grant the role to the new user manually.

This behavior doesn't always occur, sometimes the role is added, sometimes not.

The Privileged Gateway Intents for the bot configuration are both enabled (server members intent & presence intent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [response](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/4930#issuecomment-789736904)  from a contributor.

> The audits shows the bot adding the role, but when you look at the new user's profile, no role shows up.

> That suggests this is a client issue. I have had that issue myself, where the client doesn't show bot-applied roles. However, API wise the request goes through, is fulfilled and the role accordingly added. There is nothing you (or we, on the library level) can do to influence the viewing client.
>
> This is accordingly not a library issue.

If no one offers a solution, I will mark this post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you use stable version of Node (i.e 14) It can cause many unexpected things unless you know what you're doing with Node v15.

You don't need to get the role object to add the role to new member.

You can simply use role id and I never had any issue while using role id for adding roles.

```js
member.roles.add("ROLE_ID").then(console.log('Role added: ' + member.id));
```

Comment: I ran the code for weeks on my personal computer which does have NodeJs v14.15.1.
Same issue is occurring.
I'm trying your advice and add the role with the role id rather than the object, but I honestly don't think it would bother anything.

Comment: using stable node version and role id instead of role object is all I can think of.. maybe the role you're trying to fing using ID is not cached?